# Embed group from svg file into html

Tags: html, image, svg, embed

I want to embed a group from an SVG file, that can be identified with an id. My naive approaches were:

**1. embed**

```xhtml
<embed src="cards/svg-cards.svg#joker_red"
  id="embsvg"
  width="300" height="220"  type="image/svg+xml"
  pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/"  
  viewBox="0 0 100 100"
 />
```

**2. image**

```xhtml
<image id="i" x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" 
   xlink:href="cards/svg-cards.svg#joker_red" />
```

**3. object**

```xhtml
<object data="cards/svg-cards.svg#red_joker"></object>
```

and I tried some more silly variants including the USE element and javascript.

The svg document was taken from here: [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svg-cards/)

Comment: This works on Firefox doesn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/7GCGr/ displays different icons for example.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly and shows how to do what I want in a very nice way. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with my cardgame:
http://jsfiddle.net/7GCGr/142/
It will always show all cards, regardless of id. In your example it will only show the group content and nothing if no group id given.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself.

The important piece was, to give all visible elements a class attribute, say class="card" and specify 'svg .card { display: none }' as a style. That will make everything disappear. Then only the item that is selected via # behind the svg file name is actually displayed.

It doesn't really matter if the part to be displayed is a group or svg element.

Robert's posted code did it this way, but it was not obvious to me how important the class was.